# Postgresql values to columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to create view for each `destination_type` where values of `destination_type_setting.settings_name` would be columns with values of `destination_setting_value.val` or `destination_type_setting.default_val` if previous is null.

I tried to use a pivot, but as far as I understand, you need to know in advance which values to convert into columns.

[image: table scheme for destinations]

As result I want to get something like this:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|dest_name|  host   |port  | protocol|regexp|active|added settng 1|added setting2|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|name1    |localhost|1234  |http     |.*    |true  |val 1_1       | val 1_2      |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|name2    |0.0.0.0  |2222  |http     |^/d+  |false |val 2_1       | val 2_2      |
```

**UPDATE**: for now I did only simple request with joins

```
select 
    dest.destination_name, dest."host", dest.port, dest.active, 
    dts.settings_name, dsv.val 
from 
    "public".destination as dest
join 
    "public".destination_type as dt on dt."id" = dest.destination_type_fk
join 
    "public".destination_type_settings as dts on dts.destination_type_fk = dt."id"
left join 
    "public".destination_setting_value as dsv on dsv.destination_type_settings_fk = dts."id" 
                                              and dsv.destination_fk = dest."id"
where dt."id" = 7
```

Script to reproduction scheme:

```
create table destination  -- type=TABLE
(
    id bigserial not null,
    host text,
    port int4,
    protocol text,
    regexp text,
    destination_type_fk int8 not null,
    active bool not null,
    destination_name text not null,
    constraint pk_destina primary key (id)
);

create table destination_setting_value  -- type=TABLE
(
    id bigserial not null,
    destination_type_settings_fk int8 not null,
    destination_fk int8 not null,
    val text not null,
    constraint pk_supply_setting_value primary key (id)
);


create table destination_type  -- type=TABLE
(
    id bigserial not null,
    destination_type_name varchar(100),
    description text,
    constraint pk_destination_type primary key (id)
);

create table destination_type_settings  -- type=TABLE
(
    id bigserial not null,
    destination_type_fk int8 not null,
    settings_name varchar(100) not null,
    description text not null,
    default_val text not null,
    validate text not null,
    constraint pk_destination_type_srttings primary key (id),
    constraint unq_destination_type_settings unique (destination_type_fk, settings_name)
);

insert into destination_type (id, destination_type_name, description) values (7, 'http', 'http test');

insert into destination_type_settings (id, destination_type_fk, settings_name, description, default_val, validate) values (3, 7, 'added_setting_1', 'this is added setting', 'def val 1', '.*');
insert into destination_type_settings (id, destination_type_fk, settings_name, description, default_val, validate) values (4, 7, 'added_setting_2', 'this is second added setting', '15', '^/d+');

insert into destination (id, host, port, protocol, regexp, destination_type_fk, active, destination_name) values (8, 'localhost', 1234, 'http', '^.*+', 7, 'f', 'dest 1');
insert into destination (id, host, port, protocol, regexp, destination_type_fk, active, destination_name) values (9, '0.0.0.0', 2222, 'http', '.*', 7, 't', 'dest 2');

insert into destination_setting_value (id, destination_type_settings_fk, destination_fk, val) values (3, 3, 8, 'val 1_1');
insert into destination_setting_value (id, destination_type_settings_fk, destination_fk, val) values (4, 4, 8, 'val 1_2');
insert into destination_setting_value (id, destination_type_settings_fk, destination_fk, val) values (5, 3, 9, 'val 2_1');
insert into destination_setting_value (id, destination_type_settings_fk, destination_fk, val) values (6, 4, 9, 'val 2_2');
```

**UPDATE #2**

In general, I can get all additional settings for a specific destination with this query:

```
select dts.settings_name, dsv.val 
from "public".destination_type_settings as dts 
left join "public".destination_setting_value as dsv on dsv.destination_type_settings_fk = dts."id"
where dsv.destination_fk = 8
```

and got

```
settings_name   | val
----------------------
added_setting_1 | val 1_1
added_setting_2 | val 1_2
```

but I want to get with the same data next:

```
added_setting_1 | added_setting_2
---------------------------------
val 1_1         | val 1_2
```

and use it in first query described in this question, but I have no enough competition to do that.

I don't know amount of additional settings before query

Comment: Provide a complete [mcve], i.e. add sample table data too. And show us your current query attempt.

Comment: sorry, added sql request to reproduce sheme

Comment: Explain what you've tried, specify what you want, and add details to the question.

Comment: SQL is extremely powerful at data retrieval but much much less so at presentation formatting. Your upstanding that *you need to know in advance which values to convert into columns* is correct, you must know exactly the values to pivot beforehand. Well, that's not quite true, you could write code to select the values then generate a pivot query. But that can get complicated quickly. Recommendation: sort on the column to be pivoted then let your app's presentation manager format the resulting display.